# How Can I write a code to load a special dialog when I click on a menu Item in win32 project C++ application?

Tags: c++, win32gui

I work on a c++ win32 project. I have a menu bar; I want to know how can I load a special dialog which I added it to my resources before and its ID is IDC_FORMVIEW when I click on the menu Item such as "Add Marker".

Can you tell me How can I do that? is ON_COMMAND useful here? or another way there is to link them?

thank you so much!
sorry my english language is not good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends if your project is MFC or simple Win32.

If your project is MFC - open your menu in Resource View (if not visible View->Resource View). Select your menu item IDC_FORMVIEW and right click. You have option "Add Event Handler" with a list with the possible dialogs where the handler function will be placed. Select your main window and click "Add and Edit".

If your project is Win32 - you have to add it yourself in WM_COMMAND handler, see how it is done for IDM_EXIT.

To display the dialog:

For MFC projects - Select dialog, choose Add Class, choose a name for the dialog, for example SomeDlg, wizard will generate SomeDlg.h and SomeDlg.cpp. Include SomeDlg.h in your main file and in the menu handler type:

```
 void CmainDlg::OnSomeDlg()
 {
   SomeDlg dlg;
   dlg.DoModal();
 }
```

For Win32 - you have to use DialogBox, see how is done for IDM_ABOUT. You have to define your own dialog window callback:

```
 BOOL CALLBACK TestDlgProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
 { 
    switch (message) 
    { 
            case WM_INITDIALOG:
                 MessageBox(0,_T("started"),0,0);
            break;

            case WM_COMMAND: 
                switch (LOWORD(wParam)) 
                { 
                    case IDOK: 
                    case IDCANCEL: 
                     EndDialog(hwndDlg, wParam); 
                    return TRUE; 
                } 
} 
return FALSE;
```

}

And you create your (modal) dialog like this:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
    wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
    // Parse the menu selections:
    switch (wmId)
    {

    case IDM_TEST:
        if(DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), hWnd,     (DLGPROC)TestDlgProc)==IDOK)
        {
            MessageBox(0,_T("Closed with Ok"),0,0);
        }
    break;
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#modal_box

Comment: it is win32 project; Yeah! I create a function for handling the operation when I click on the item and using the ON_COMMAND I completed it; Now it is working such as you said above; thank you so much Baj for your great help :)